# Link a text to specific url in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to link a part of text to a url, in React.
Here's an example of code.

```
{ abc ? <Random /> : 'Go to this page.'}
```

**page** needs to be linked to a specific url. Can anyone please help me with this?

Comment: Wrap the text with `<a>` ?

Comment: @SinanYaman won't work.

Answer (score 0):

`{ abc ? <Random /> :  <span> Go to this <Link to='/path'> page </Link></span>}`

Hope this Helps It will Redirect you to the page you want.

Comment: I want only *page* to act as a hyperlink, not the whole text.

Comment: The above edited fixes the issue.

Answer (score -1):

like this :

```
{  abc ? <Random /> : <a href="https://www.google.com">go to google</a>}
```

Comment: I think the question was more about how to link only the word "page".

Comment: Yes, I need the *page* to act as a hyperlink.